# Jagged array by declared arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I searched and could not find the solution in C#

I have declared and assigned arrays :

```
string[] arr1 = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
string[] arr2 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
string[] arr3 = {"s","t","a","c","k","o"};
string[] arr4 = {"v","e","r","f","l","w"};
```

I want to make a jagged array from those arrays, but did not succeed.

```
string[,] port = new string[]
{
    new string[] arr1[],
    new string[] arr2[],
    new string[] arr3[],
    new string[] arr4[],
};
```

Where is the mistake I make?

My program will produce random `int`s to call a value from the jagged array

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.Next(0,5);
int y = random.Next(0,3);
Console.WriteLine(port[y,x]);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of arrays?

Comment: yes I am but could not make it ,  it is sort of 2 dimensional array how ever I  need to make that array from the declared arrays

Comment: in short `[,]` is for multidimensional and `[][]` is for jagged

Comment: so to make it 3 dimensional should I use [ , , ] or [ ][ ][ ]

Comment: now I expanded 2 dimensional to 3 but the last time I was using all arrays same with same column no one array has 2 element other one has 4 and the last one has 14

and failed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

1. You don't declare a **jagged** array, but a **multi-dimensional** one. Since your "inner" arrays are already defined, you need an *array of arrays* here, which is called "jagged" array.
2. You don't need the `new string[]` in the declaration as you already declared the inner arrays

So this should work:

```
string[][] port = new string[][]
{
    arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4
};
```

or with array initializer even shorter:

```
string[][] port = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
```

---

To access this array use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(port[y][x]);
```

Comment: seems I don't understand the logic of Jagged Array; thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] arr1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
string[] arr2 = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
string[] arr3 = { "s", "t", "a", "c", "k", "o" };
string[] arr4 = { "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "w" };

string[][] port = new string[4][];
port[0] = arr1;
port[1] = arr2;
port[2] = arr3;
port[3] = arr4;
```

Or simply:

```
string[][] port = new string[][] { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
```

Usage:

```
string test = port[1][5];
```

Comment: thanks mm8 , it is very nice of you to share 2 solution at once.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answer :D you two helped me a lot